# How can I use the JS code generated by the atscc2js compiler?

Tags: ats

I know how to use patsopt and atscc2js to compile ATS code into JS code:

```
patsopt -d foo.dats | atscc2js -o foo_dats.js
```

Do I need to include some kind of JS library for atscc2js in order to run the JS code in foo_dats.js?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will need to include at least [libatscc2js_all.js](http://ats-lang.sourceforge.net/LIBRARY/contrib/libatscc/libatscc2js/libatscc2js_all.js).